# Prevent style from applying to ::after

Tags: html, css

Demonstration: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/85LNE/</kbd>

Right now I have the following CSS style applied to links to add separators:

```css
div > a{
    color: #2679c1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div > a:hover{
    color: #3096fb;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
div > a:not(:last-child)::after{
    content: ' ‧ ';
}
```

This works however when I hover over the link, the separator are also underlined. I was hoping by adding the following rule it would solve the problem, but it apparently has no effect:

```css
div > a:not(:last-child):hover::after{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any solutions? (I don't really want to wrap the content with a `<span>` because it defeats the purpose of using CSS to simplify the process of adding the separators.)

Comment: You don't want underlines on any of the links or just the last one?

Comment: @AliGajani he doesn't want the underline effect to be inherited by the `::after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/85LNE/3/)

[image]

Try adding the `display:inline-block;` to your `a:not(:last-child)::after`.

You can add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to make the `.` appear with the same gap.

```
a:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: ' ‧ ';
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: I changed my answer, waiting for him to come back and up-vote.

Comment: A/w +1 from me was curious as how to solve it, inline-block slipped my mind

Comment: @AliGajani - This solves my problem, and by the way, thanks for the `pre-wrap` trick! PS: I don't know who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Someone by mistake but I am happy I helped you. That's what matters the most :)

Comment: I downvoted, because originally his answer removed **all** underlining effects. I've rescinded it now though, after the edit. I was in the process of commenting to explain the DV when the original answer was deleted. Anyway, nice solution, @AliGajani! +1.